# Features to 3D from 2D in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, 3d

Is there a way to convert 2D features to "3D" features in QGIS?  I know there is a way to do this in ArcMap by using an attribute value in the attribute table, but I am looking to do this with shapefiles in QGIS.

Comment: I want to convert to 3D from 2D

Comment: Convert what? Lines, polygons, points?

Comment: a pleasure to greet How can I convert a 3d polyline shape to a 2d in QGis? Thank you

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/122106)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [v.to.3d module](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.to.3d.html) in the GRASS toolkit (installed with QGIS) to do 2d to 3d layer transformation:

> v.to.3d - Performs transformation of 2D vector features to 3D.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the exact tool, however, when I look for the tool in the GRASS Tools I do not see it.  There are four tools available (r.topidx, vdrape, v.random and nviz) when filtered by 3D, but no v.to.3d.  I am new to Grass Tools, is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: The module is new to version 6.4.0, see link http://grass.osgeo.org/announces/announce_grass640.html

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the newest version of Grass (6.4.1-1).  After installation I do not see the v.to.3d tool available within QGIS.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I am using the QGIS 2.14 in portuguese, but I'll try to show you the steps with pics bellow.

1- Click in save as

[image]

2- On the "save window" choose the option "inclui dimensao-z" in english is equal to "include Z data" I think.

[image]