# Creating 3D model in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d

Can I create a 3D model in QGIS or is there some model for 3D city models?

Comment: There is a similar question with an answer that may help here  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27937/features-to-3d-from-2d-in-qgis

Answer (score 7):

QGIS 3.0 will support rendering of 3D models out of the box. Install the latest nightly build of QGIS using OSGEO4W or another installer for your platform.

1. Add 3D Canvas from main menu `View > New 3D Map View`
2. Add your 3D model as new layer
3. In style panel, enable 3D renderer.

Comment: What type of 3D models does this feature support?  I'm trying to use a .dae file and it doesn't seem to be working.  QGIS isn't offering any advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is QGIS Globe. You'll need to run QGIS on Linux though (Source http://sourcepole.ch/the-state-of-qgis-globe).

To see QGIS Globe with PostGIS 3D in action check http://vimeo.com/54776907.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a plugin based on a JavaScript library [link here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Qgis2threejs/)

This plugin will generate an html page where you will be able to pan in 3d

Comment: I try to use it, but it gives bad results for me. It's make 2d features 3d based on attribute for example "height", and after export to JS, I cant work with features geometry. And it will be html document instead QGraphicsView, so I can't add some objects dynamically, for example pictures. I want to add models to map with roof, windows and other building attributes. Something like Google Earth. It also show 2d map and 3d models of building over it.

Comment: You can use 3d shapefiles, you dont need to have a height attribute. And yes it is limited ATM. I'm afraid that QGIS doesn't propose anything like this.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. After using 3d shapefiles I need to make export to js, or add it to scene? Scene is 2d, so i cant turn it and see building from all sides, just from top?