# Replacing Z-field in vector file with attribute table column for export as Z-enabled KML using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml, 3d

Using QGIS, I have been unable to take a height field contained within the attribute table of a vector file, and make that height field the z-value of that point.

QGIS doesn't seem to have the ability to create/alter Z-values within the core program, I would rather not have to deal with SpatiaLite databases if I don't have to, which is the only other method I have heard mentioned.

Also tried v.to.3d as suggested here 
[Features to 3D from 2D in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27937/features-to-3d-from-2d-in-qgis)

and got either an empty output, an OGR "Data source is invalid ()" message, or both.  I am working with a shapefile if that is relevant.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Please [edit] to focus on a specific GIS software that you'd like an answer for.  If you need an answer for both please ask them separately.

Comment: Ok, I will specify Q for this post, and Arc for another then.

Comment: It's usually best to ask the more pressing question first, and wait to see if there are problems which will garner requests for clarification (and downvotes) before posting a near duplicate.

Comment: The possible solutions for me are platform agnostic, although I prefer QGIS, I am willing to work with a solution in either.  I thought it easier to post a single question which pertained to both platforms, but apparently that is too broad, so I asked a question pertaining to each platform.  My questions aren't duplicates, as they use different tools in different software packages.